# Random directions for each spheres in 3D animation

Tags: python, animation, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D animation with each sphere moving in a random direction(up, down, to the left, to the right, backward or forward). They are all moving in a 3D world (each sphere has a random X,Y and Z value), and it is projected on a 2D screen. While I am expecting each sphere to move independently from the other spheres in a random direction, the spheres appear to move in one direction altogether, as shown here.[image]

I do not understand why it behaves this way given my code :

```
# random X, Y, Z: fill X, Y and Z coordinates with uniform random values that serve as coordinates 

for sphere in spheres:
    sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size=2)
    sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(z_near, z_far)

# Create two angles for each sphere, theta and phi, to compute the change of direction.

     sphere.theta_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360; # Angle thera controls the horizontal orientation of the gaze.
     sphere.phi_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360;   # Angle Phi controls the vertical orientation of the gaze.

# Different directions

speed = 3;                                             #degrees/seconds
theta_rad = sphere.theta_deg * np.pi /180;              #direction converted to radians
phi_rad = sphere.phi_deg* np.pi /180;                   #direction converted to radians

dx = speed*np.sin(-phi_rad-theta_rad)/frameRate;
dy = -speed*np.cos(phi_rad + theta_rad)/frameRate;
dz = -speed*np.cos(theta_rad)/frameRate;    

while 1:

     # Modulate the angular directions
     dx = speed*np.sin(-phi_rad-theta_rad)/frameRate;
     dy = -speed*np.cos(phi_rad + theta_rad)/frameRate;
     dz = -speed*np.cos(theta_rad)/frameRate;

     for sphere in spheres:

         # Update Spheres Positions
         sphere.position.x += dx
         sphere.position.y += dy
         sphere.position.z += dz
```

The sphere position should update at each frame and should be random.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the `while` loop the program calculates a single `theta_rad` and a single `phi_rad` from  the `theta_deg` and `phi_deg` values of the final sphere in the `spheres` list.  It then uses that `theta_rad` and `phi_rad` to calculate a single `dx`, a single `dy` and a single `dz`.  And then it uses a `for` loop to apply those `dx`, `dy` and `dz` values to every sphere in the list.  All of the spheres in the list get exactly the same increments, and that's why they all move in the same direction.

(The program also recalculates exactly the same `dx`, `dy` and `dz` values every time it goes through the `while` loop.  That doesn't cause any additional damage, it's just pointless.)

To fix, you need to calculate separate `theta_rad` and `phi_rad` values for each individual sphere (based on each sphere's unique `theta_deg` and `phi_deg` attributes); you need to use those per-sphere `theta_rad` and `phi_rad` values to calculate separate `dx`, `dy` and `dz` values for every sphere; and you need to store those per-sphere `dx`, `dy` and `dz` values as attributes of that sphere.

Then each time around the `while` loop you will adjust each individual sphere's `position.x`, `position.y` and `position.z` by adding that sphere's own `dx`, `dy` and `dz` values.

You can do all of the extra per-sphere calculation and storing inside the first `for` loop.  It will become something like this:

```
speed = 3  # define this before the 'for' loop so that we can use it inside the loop

for sphere in spheres:
    sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size=2)
    sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(z_near, z_far)

    sphere.theta_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360
    sphere.phi_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360

    theta_rad = sphere.theta_deg * np.pi / 180
    phi_rad = sphere.phi_deg* np.pi / 180

    sphere.dx = speed * np.sin(-phi_rad - theta_rad) / frameRate
    sphere.dy = -speed * np.cos(phi_rad + theta_rad) / frameRate
    sphere.dz = -speed * np.cos(theta_rad) / frameRate
```

Your while loop will become much simpler, basically:

```
while 1:
    for sphere in spheres:
        sphere.position.x += sphere.dx
        sphere.position.y += sphere.dy
        sphere.position.z += sphere.dz
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for the explanation and the solution. It works marvellously good now!